# can I put HAVING with select query

Tags: mysql

I have  this SQL code

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(e.clients_idclients) FROM experienced e JOIN designation d WHERE e.designation_iddesignation = d.iddesignation AND e.clients_idclients = clients.idclients AND d.iddesignation IN('268'))as de_count 
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `experienced` ON `experienced`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `designation` ON `designation`.`iddesignation` = `experienced`.`designation_iddesignation`
LEFT JOIN `industry` ON `industry`.`idindustry` = `experienced`.`industry_idindustry`
LEFT JOIN `company` ON `company`.`idcompany` = `experienced`.`company_idcompany`
LEFT JOIN `academic_qualifications` ON `academic_qualifications`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `qulification` ON `qulification`.`idqulification` = `academic_qualifications`.`qulification_idqulification`
LEFT JOIN `institute` ON `institute`.`idinstitute` = `academic_qualifications`.`institute_idinstitute`
LEFT JOIN `job_category` ON `experienced`.`job_category_idjobCategory` = `job_category`.`idjobCategory`
LEFT JOIN `client_tag` ON `client_tag`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `cv` ON `cv`.`clients_idclients` = `clients`.`idclients`
LEFT JOIN `tag` ON `tag`.`idtag` = `client_tag`.`tag_idtag`
WHERE `clients`.`status_idstatus` != '10'
AND `clients`.`clientsAge` >= '0'
AND `clients`.`clientsAge` <= '100'
AND `clients`.`clientsOtherQualifications` = '1'
AND (`clients`.`fullName` LIKE '%custorme%'  OR `clients`.`clientsEmail` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `designation`.`designationName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `cv`.`cvName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `industry`.`industryName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `company`.`companyName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `qulification`.`qulificationName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `institute`.`instituteName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `job_category`.`jobCategoryName` LIKE '%custorme%' OR `tag`.`tagName` LIKE '%custorme%')
GROUP BY `clients`.`idclients`
HAVING de_count > 0
ORDER BY `clients`.`idclients` DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Can I write this  SQL code as

```
HAVING > (SELECT COUNT(e.clients_idclients) FROM experienced e JOIN designation d WHERE e.designation_iddesignation = d.iddesignation AND e.clients_idclients = clients.idclients AND d.iddesignation IN('268'))
```

without defining it next to the top select?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you mention the "tag" . As which RDBMS you are using this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess "yes".  But I would not ask anyone, I would simply try it.  It is non-destructive, etc; trying is much faster and easier than waiting for an answer.